# com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.IllegalPdfSyntaxException: Unbalanced save/restore state operators

Tags: java, itext

I am getting the `com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.IllegalPdfSyntaxException:` Unbalanced save/restore state operators exception at times when i tried to generate the PDF from j2e web application.

I am using `PdfGraphics2D` object to draw the text and shapes due to sync with other swing application.

Can anybody give some hand to get out from this. I am unable to move forward since it is **working some times** and some times **it throws exception**, what could be the cause?

I am using `itextpdf-5.2.1.jar`. Please let me know you need any information.

I have look into the source code of dispose method in PdfGraphics2D object it is as below

```
 /**
 * @see Graphics#dispose()
 */
@Override
public void dispose() {
    if (kid)
        return;
    if (!disposeCalled) {
        disposeCalled = true;
        cb.restoreState();
        cb.restoreState();
        if (dg2 != null) {
            dg2.dispose();
            dg2 = null;
        }
        if (kids != null) {
            ByteBuffer buf = new ByteBuffer();
            internalDispose(buf);
            ByteBuffer buf2 = cb.getInternalBuffer();
            buf2.reset();
            buf2.append(buf);
        }
    }
}
```

why `cb.restoreState();` method called twice.

Please let me know if any body knows about this or direct to me solve the issue.

Thanks
Dhorrairaajj

Comment: why you are calling cb.restoreState(); method twice.

Comment: This is a bug about 'balancing' calls to a pair of methods. You need to consider more of your code, possibly covering the whole life-cycle of the object `cb`.

Comment: *why `cb.restoreState();` method called twice.* - look at the parameterized `PdfGraphics2D` constructors, they call `cb.saveState()` twice. Thus, `dispose()` has to call `cb.restoreState()` twice, too.

Comment: Concerning your original issue: Please provide a reproducible sample. And anyway consider updating, 5.2.1 is ancient and many issues have been fixed since that version.

Comment: Hi Dan Allen, Thanks for reply and suggestion, how can i fix since it working first attempt and then throwing exception from then, any possible reason did you know?

Comment: Hi mkl, Thanks for clarifiying why restorestate is called twice, do you know any reason for this, in middle of program i have many times creating CustomePdfGraphic object and closing too, Is this any problem?

Comment: *do you know any reason for this* - you said you use iText this way to *sync with other swing application*. Swing applications usually are multi-threaded (unless they are very simple or inadequately implemented. iText documents are not thread-safe, though. If your Swing application possibly accesses an iText document from multiple threads, proper synchronization might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

@Override
public void dispose() {

```
if (kid)
    return;
if (!disposeCalled) {
    disposeCalled = true;
    //you are calling restoreState() twice. check it
    cb.restoreState();
    cb.restoreState();
    if (dg2 != null) {
        dg2.dispose();
        dg2 = null;
    }
    if (kids != null) {
        ByteBuffer buf = new ByteBuffer();
        internalDispose(buf);
        ByteBuffer buf2 = cb.getInternalBuffer();
        buf2.reset();
        buf2.append(buf);
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for you reply, kid,disposeCalled and dg2 are private instance variables can not able to override.

Comment: *you are calling restoreState() twice. check it* - look at the parameterized `PdfGraphics2D` constructors, they call `cb.saveState()` twice. Thus, `dispose()` has to call `cb.restoreState()` twice, too.